# Return multiple information from angular route resolver

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, resolver

I'm facing an issue concerning the return of the resolver in my application.

Basically that's my resolver :

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
  resolve() {
    /*
    this.authService.token; // (property) PeAuthService.authorizationHeader: string
    this.authService.getUserInfo(); // (method) PeAuthService.getUserInfos(): Observable<any>
    */
    return {
      token: this.authService.token,
      userInfo: this.authService.getUserInfo()
    };
  }
```

I dont't feel like I'm doing the correct way, because I can access the token value but not the userInfo.

Is there any way to return one observable containing userinfo data and the token ? So maybe combining an observable and a string in one observable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More "Rx" way would be getting `getUserInfo()` and then combining it with `this.authService.token` using the `map()` operator:

```
this.authService.getUserInfo()
  .pipe(
    map(userInfo => ({
      userInfo,
      token: this.authService.token,
    }))
  );
```

Comment: There is a problem in your syntax no ?

Comment: the map function I'm getting : Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'? I used map alone though it worked well

Comment: You need to import the `map()` operator from `rxjs/operators`

Answer (score 0):

Without awaiting the value, the `userInfo` property of the returned object contains the `Observable`. Therefore, simply use `async` and `await`:

```js
async resolve() {
  return {
    token: this.authService.token,
    userInfo: await this.authService.getUserInfo()
  };
}
```